# How to Display only specific slides on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using jquery filter effects to sort certain div slides in a page but i hope to only have the default chosen ['active'] div displaying on page load instead of all the divs containing the other slides. Please note that the filter effect is working but on page load, all the divs come up.

html layout selector:

```
 <div class="details-selector">
            <ul>
              <li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="*">all</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-filter=".filter-bodypaint">body-Paint</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-filter=".filter-makeup">beauty</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-filter=".filter-theatre">theatre</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-filter=".filter-effects">effects</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 article-wrap filter-effects">   Slides-effects </div>
```

slides-makeup

javascript:

```
initIsotope : function() {
        var $container = $('.hp-portfolio-three').isotope({
            // options
            itemSelector : '.article-wrap',
            layoutMode : 'fitRows'
        });
        $('.details-selector a').click(function() {
            $('.details-selector ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            var $el = $(this);
            $el.parent().addClass('active');
            var selector = $el.attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
            return false;
        });
        $('.category-selector').on('change', function() {
            var selector = $(this).val();
            $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
        });
    },
```

I have tried removing and deleting the class 'active' on the first

and placing it on the second

but to no success.

Comment: jsFiddle please

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be caused by the delay between your HTML (DOM) loading and the jQuery running. Could you try hiding all slides in CSS until the jQuery reveals the ones you want? It looks like you are also using the very excellent isotope. Do you have a sample page we could look at?